# What does this function do and How to rewrite without the 'with' statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, with-statement

Javascript:

```
function ValidDate(y, m, d)
{ // m = 0..11 ; y m d integers, y!=0
  with (new Date(y, m, d))
    return (getMonth()==m && getDate()==d); /* was y, m */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
function ValidDate(y, m, d) {
  var date = new Date(y, m, d);
  return date.getMonth() == m && date.getDate() == d;
}
```

Comment: var date = new Date(y, m, d)) should be var date = new Date(y, m, d); I believe otherwise this works.

Comment: @JoshuaFricke: thanks for edit, C&P error. +1 for your answer as well :-).

Answer (score 3):

`with` makes it so that the `this` scope is the statement in the `with` so you don't have to do any `.functionName(...)`

What you can do:

```
function ValidDate(y, m, d)
{ // m = 0..11 ; y m d integers, y!=0
    var date = new Date(y, m, d);
    return (date.getMonth()==m && date.getDate()==d); /* was y, m */
}
```